# the column in csv that comes from the index of DataFrame does not have a header name

Tags: pandas

here is a pandas DataFrame

```
>>> print(df)
   A  B  C
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8
```

with `df.to_csv('df.csv')` I got this file

[image]

the column in csv that comes from the index of DataFrame does not have a header name. Is it possible to specify a column name with pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `rename_axis`

```
df.rename_axis('index').to_csv('df.csv')
```